# Unable to access Jenkins from browser on Windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, centos, vmware

I installed Jenkins on CentOS 7 running in VMware Workstation. Jenkins Service is running:

```
 jenkins.service - Jenkins Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-06-21 08:47:46 PDT; 5s ago
 Main PID: 68969 (java)
   Memory: 82.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
           └─68969 java -jar /usr/local/bin/jenkins.war

Jun 21 08:47:48 server.centos.lan java[68969]: Jun 21, 2016 8:47:48 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
Jun 21 08:47:48 server.centos.lan java[68969]: INFO: Started ServerConnector@34ddf859{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Jun 21 08:47:48 server.centos.lan java[68969]: Jun 21, 2016 8:47:48 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
Jun 21 08:47:48 server.centos.lan java[68969]: INFO: Started @2472ms
Jun 21 08:47:48 server.centos.lan java[68969]: Jun 21, 2016 8:47:48 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
Jun 21 08:47:48 server.centos.lan java[68969]: INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Jun 21 08:47:49 server.centos.lan java[68969]: Jun 21, 2016 8:47:49 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
Jun 21 08:47:49 server.centos.lan java[68969]: INFO: Started initialization
Jun 21 08:47:49 server.centos.lan java[68969]: Jun 21, 2016 8:47:49 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
Jun 21 08:47:49 server.centos.lan java[68969]: INFO: Listed all plugins
```

IP of VM is 192.168.139.160. Host operating system is Windows 7.

When I try to access Jenkins from browser on Windows using http://192.168.139.160:8080/jenkins I get error:
"This site can’t be reached". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed Jenkins on CentOS 7.1, you should add a rule in firewall for port 8080, or at least disable firewalld.

To disable firewalld, you can use these commands:

> systemctl stop firewalld
>
> systemctl disable firewalld

After this you should be able to reach Jenkins on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

**Stop Firewall + start tomcat**

Find where you have the iptables, then put them down like this:
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
(might be some different location on your computer)

Then start up the tomcat you'll have a script like this:
startup.sh (in my computer the path is /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/bin/)

Answer (score -1):

Please try it out.

First

```
JENKINS_HTTPS_LISTEN_ADDRESS="Public IP"  >> /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

Then

```
/etc/init.d/jenkins restart
```

Comment: The Jenkins service described here is a SystemD service.  At least the second line of your answer will not work.